# how to solve error expected a value of type "String", but got one of type "Null" in this package

Tags: flutter, events, calendar, package

i'm using flutter event calendar from https://github.com/novaday-co/flutter_event_calendar/tree/3420cc68693ebfa654e071a8a0a8d68763e530a3
when i install package and use it like below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_calendar/flutter_event_calendar.dart';

class Event extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: EventCalendar(
 
        events: [
          Event(
            title: 'Laravel Event',
            description:
                'The largest Laravel event of the year, streamed directly to you. We’ve put 
                     together a full day of talks featuring some of Laravel’s brightest minds, and 
                     streaming them directly to your home or office.',
            dateTime: "2022-03-11 20:00",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

return me this error

[image]

and when add calendarType like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_event_calendar/flutter_event_calendar.dart';

class SHOP_SCREEN extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: EventCalendar(
        calendarType: CalendarType.Jalali ,
        calendarLanguage: 'fa',
        canSelectViewType: true,
        events: [
          Event(
            title: 'Laravel Event',
            description:
                'The largest Laravel event of the year, streamed directly to you. We’ve put together a full day of talks featuring some of Laravel’s brightest minds, and streaming them directly to your home or office.',
            dateTime: "2022-03-11 20:00",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

return me this error

[image]

and this is error in terminal

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart      
251:49      throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 84:3 
castError
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart
452:10  cast
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 652:17
as
packages/flutter_event_calendar/src/handlers/EventCalendar.dart 90:19    <========= important(self added)
new
```

i tried

> calendarType: CalendarType.Jalali as CalendarType ,

> calendarType: CalendarType.Jalali as String,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, at the time of answering this question, as per the docs, 'calenderType' property is not annotated as required in the constructor of EventCalendar class and if you don't pass any value to it, it is being set to 'Gregorian' by default.

[See the last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6qx6.png)

So, can't understand why is it giving the error. But, I'll suggest you to try out one of these:

1. try using toString() method on it instead of 'as String'.
2. Try passing 'jalali' directly to the parameter. Suggesting this on my observation of the code in the README of this plugin: [flutter_event_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_event_calendar)

[Look at the 1st parameter being passed to EventCalendar() constructor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnVeu.jpg)

Comment: first of all i usded toString() instead of ' as String ' return to me "expected value type of CalendarType but got one of type "Null"